# Is it possible to use $regex to query hyperledger using CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to query my blockchain (based on hyperledger fabric), searching for a specific matching pattern.
I have this request:

```
{
    "selector": {
        "book": { "$regex":"(?i)(%s)+" }
    }
}
```

The "%s" represent the string sent to the function of the chaincode.

This is not working in my case, it send me back an empty json.
I don't even know if it is possible with hyperledger fabric.

Maybe there is an other way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean "is not working"?   Please be more specific. What doesn't work? What error do you get, or what output do you get? What did you expect instead?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I mad a mistake in my invoke function...